# Emacs-Tramp: Not working properly

Tags: emacs, tramp

I'm trying to use Tramp/Emacs-23 in Ubuntu 12.04 in order to edit the remote host files. My remote host has two step authentication (RSA+Passwd). I use multiplexing through .ssh/config to ensure that tramp can directly connect to the remote shell without having to provide passwords.

My problem however is that I have 3 different remote hosts. When I try to connect to remote host through tramp without the initial multiplexing (through terminal), the TRAMP hangs with a message stating "**Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell**". I used the below mentioned commands in .ssh/config to ensure the connection gets lost after a specified interval upon no prompt.

```
Host *
ServerAliveCountMax=30
ServerAliveInterval=5
```

However this doesn't seem to have any effect on the tramp connection. It will be of help if someone can help me in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that your question has been left hanging so long.

I can offer a couple of things to try, use the tramp protocol `sshx` instead of `ssh`, it seems to cope better with most non-vanilla ssh connections.

e.g.

```
/sshx:user@host:path/filename
```

The other thing to try is adding your ssh key passphrase to the session at startup, run an `ssh-agent` on the machine, and connect to it at startup, then run `ssh-add` to enter the passphrase once.

As a side note, upgrade your Emacs to 24.3 there's a lot of new/great stuff in there since 23.x

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I did fix the issue even with Emacs 23. The issue was I was using emacs-snapshot instead of stable version which created problems. Further the two step authentication was solved by  using `ControlMaster auto` in the ssh config file.